# (Jmonkey Engine) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find animation named: 'Idle' How do I solve this? Thanks

Tags: jmonkeyengine

I would like to have help  with a error I'm are currently having  for the Jmonkey Engine 3 and possibly help others if they are getting the same or similar message. 
I keep getting this error, when I run/build the project

[image: 1]

But  when I put the model in the scene composer and go into AnimControl the animations when I play them work. The Code can be uploaded to an Image if requested.

[image: 2]

PS : I cannot ask this question on the jmonkey official forms  as I have forgetten my password and the rest email will not arrive in my Inbox.

Answer (score 1):

Can you play the other animations (Head Turn for example)? Are you sure that you load the correct model and that you are in the correct position of the Node (the Node, where also the AnimControl is)? Otherwise it has to be a spelling error, for example ldle (with a 'l') instead of Idle (with an 'I').

Comment: Yes thanks for helping yes I can play the head turn in the scene composer.

Comment: But can you play the Head Turn animation in your application from code or does it tell you that it can't find the animation?